# Decorators not supported yet in 6.x error

Tags: javascript, babeljs, aurelia

I'm trying to run Jasmine tests while using Babel to transpile.

Every time i try to run the tests, which are written in Aurelia.js syntax, I keep getting hit with the Decorators are not supported error(my Babel version is 6.3.15)

I have the following in my .babelrc file:

**.babelrc**

```json
{
  "presets":["es2015", "stage-0", "stage-1"],
  "plugins":["transform-class-properties", "transform-decorators"]
}
```

and the snippet it fails on is:

```js
@inject(HttpClient)
export class Users {
  heading = "test";
  users = [];
```

Surely Babel should transform the decorators given one of the presets contaisn the plugin for it? Even if that failed, wouldn't my transform-decorators plugin catch it instead?Also, Initially this was done with Babel 5.8.23 and i was still seeing this error, so i changed the package number to latest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorators are broken in Babel 6!

[Here's](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2645) the issue in the babel issue tracker.

Based on [this reply](https://twitter.com/sebmck/status/661501967412301824) it might be a while before the issue is fixed.

After downgrading to Babel 5, make sure your babel options have `stage: 0` or the `es7.decorators` option.  Here's where you need to configure the options:

- [config.js](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/config.js#L6)
- [build/babel-options.js](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/build/babel-options.js)
- [karma.conf.js](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/karma.conf.js#L42)

Comment: Ah so there is no work around at the minute? I think i can remove the decorators for now but still, would've been handy to have it hookedu p with the latest version

Comment: there might be a workaround given all he discussion in the babel issue.  Babel 6 is buggy which is why they haven't updated the [repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/).  You may want to stay on 5 until they sort things out.

Comment: so ive got stage 0, and the es7 property in build/babel-options, and the es7 property in config.js and karma.conf.js but now im getting errors about  "unexpected reserved word import"

Comment: Is the code being transformed at all?  What does the source code look like in the debugger?

Comment: well im running it off of a command line, using Jasmine. So im more or less just making config changes, cmd jasmine then watch the results. How would i debug it?

Comment: Ive checked my dist folder after building with gulp, it transforms the code fine and it is using es7.decorators, es7.classProperties and stage 0 so im not sure what the issue is with jasmine

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your babel options contain the following:

```
optional: [
  "es7.decorators",
  ...
]
```

They should be in both config.js (for SystemJS) an karma.conf.js (for karma).

Comment: I have this in both config.js and karma.conf.js. Is it something im missing in the .babelrc file?

Comment: I don't have anything in .babelrc and all woks great. Same is true for aurelia-navigation sample app.

Comment: hmm, I'll try removing the .babelrc file and see what happens. At the minute im having troubles with karma so i cant use it, so I'm trying to use jasmine just to run the specs for now

Comment: Yeah that didnt work now it just complains it cant find jasmin.json